# An item with the same key has already been added in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on sql clr application, after integrating with sql, I am getting this error (for English it's working but problems while adding Unicodes to dictionory):

```
**Msg 6522, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or     aggregate "SqlCompare": 
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.
System.ArgumentException: 
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value,      Boolean add)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at Translate_Class_NUM..ctor()
   at StringPercentageCompare..ctor()
   at UserDefinedFunctions.SqlComparison()**

 here is my code in c#
private   Dictionary<string, string> MyDictionary;
//private string[,] MyArray;

public Translate_Class_NUM()
{
    MyDictionary.Add("?", "01");
    MyDictionary.Add("?", "02");
    MyDictionary.Add("?", "03");
    MyDictionary.Add("?", "04");
    MyDictionary.Add("?", "05")
}
```

and in sql server code is 
    CREATE ASSEMBLY DBDB_DeDuplication 
AUTHORIZATION dbo
from 'E:\Projects\DBDB_DeDuplication\DBDB_DeDuplication\obj\Debug\DBDB_DeDuplication.dll' 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

CREATE FUNCTION SqlCompare() RETURNS nvarchar(50) 
AS EXTERNAL NAME DBDB_DeDuplication.UserDefinedFunctions.SqlComparison;
GO

SELECT dbo.SqlCompare();
GO

thanks in advance

Comment: You can't add multiple values to the same key. `MyDictionary.Add("?", "01");` places the value string `"01"` under the key `"?"` and the following line will fail because it uses the same key `"?"`. You could use the `MyDictionary["?"] = "01"` syntax instead and it wouldn't error, but you'd be overwriting your prior values under that key. Something is wrong with your dictionary usage--did you switch your values and keys?

Comment: S understood... ? in the sense different char in unicode.. here its displaying as ? only.. but in code i am using different unicode chars

Comment: S. it is working for dictionary.add("a","01") dictionary.add("b","02")  but not working for unicode Chars like ... dictionary.add("ಅ","01") dictionary.add("ಇ","02")

Comment: Try using the Unicode character literal encoding (U+0000 to U+FFFF). The error is quite clear that your keys are the same. Did you save the source file with ASCII encoding? If so, all your Unicode chars were down-converted into actual question marks.

Comment: I am frustrated by this work .. pl any one can help

Comment: No, there is no any conversion in that ,, just using this dictionary for comparing the Unicode character

Comment: @Santhosh - You should use the "@username" when replying to someone so they get a notification.

Answer (score 2):

This code works just fine for me:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("ಅ","01");
dict.Add("ಇ","02");
```

As I tried to explain before in the comments, your Unicode string must not be passing through to the compiler in the way you expect. Sometimes this can be due to the C# source file being saved with ASCII encoding or other non-Unicode supporting encoding. To guarantee results, use the C# Unicode literal encoding (U+0000 to U+FFFF).

If you don't know how to get the equivalent Unicode escape sequence, you can use this code:

```
static string EncodeNonAsciiCharacters( string value )
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach( char c in value ) {
        if( c > 127 ) {
            // This character is too big for ASCII
            string encodedValue = "\\u" + ((int) c).ToString( "x4" );
            sb.Append( encodedValue );
        }
        else {
            sb.Append( c );
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}

Console.WriteLine(EncodeNonAsciiCharacters("ಅ"));
\u0c85
Console.WriteLine(EncodeNonAsciiCharacters("ಇ"));
\u0c87
```

So then you can write the *safer* version of the source code as:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("\u0c85","01");
dict.Add("\u0c87","02");
```